# CIFS mounted W10 share dies when left idle

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, network-shares, samba

I'm running a Plex server in a headless HyperV Ubuntu server virtual machine. The media is stored in a Windows 10 share, mounted via CIFS. My fstab entries look like this:

`//<share> <mountpoint> cifs uid=<myuid>, credentials=<credentials>, iocharset=utf8, sec=ntlm 0 0`

I've been using this setup for a couple of months now with no problems. Suddenly, the mounted shares started to throw errors when left idle. For example I can stream media for two hours straight, no problem, but once I leave the server idle for a couple of minutes the mounts stop responding. The only thing that fixes the problem is rebooting the virtual machine or a force `umount` and a `mount -a`.

the error I get:
`CIFS VFS: Error -104 sending data on socket to server`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up periodically touching a file on the mounted share, as described in this relevant ServerFault question.

This is a workaround, not a solution.

https://serverfault.com/a/623730/415757